# Hide links from List Component in WebSphere Portal

Tags: websphere-portal, wcm

Currently the list component just shows all items (links) but I'm trying to find a way to hide a certain links, based on the logged in user role.

It seems that `[Plugin:Equals]` and `[Plugin:NotEquals]` tags allow us to conditionally show/hide the links, so I think this is probably the approach can try. But when it comes to getting the user access role/group info, I feel a bit stuck.

For now, I am only able to find the following fields that are available for use:

- `${wp.user.cn}`
- `${wp.user.sn}`
- `${wp.user.uid}`
- `${wp.user.preferredLanguage}`

And the online document doesn't say much either. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/dev-theme/themeopt_el_bean_user.html

So is it possible to get the assigned user access group via **wp.user**? Or perhaps there are other ways to show/hide the links in the list component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not via wp.user  you would need to use the access control model, but would be better using the attribute based security

Answer (score 0):

WCM Security will hide any links the current user doesn't have access to - be it a Site Area, Content Item / Link. Check your security on the objects which shouldn't be showing. You'll most likely find you haven't restricted access.